# Can't come up with the correct result.(order of operations) Could you please help?

Tags: arithmetic

I have the following exercise:

$$2\cdot \{100\cdot 3-3\cdot [100-3\cdot (100-3\cdot 33)]\}$$

I've looked into the text book and the correct answer is $18$ but I keep getting $-99$.

Here's how I solve it:
    $$2[100\cdot 3-3\cdot (100-3\cdot 100-99)] =
    2\cdot (100\cdot 3-300-300-99) \\= 
    600-300-300-99=-99 $$

Could you please help me out? Can't find out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try finishing the calculation in the inner most parentheses before doing the multiply by $3$ outside of it. You don't appear to be distributing properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take it in small steps. Do multiplication before addition:
$$\begin{align}
2*\{100*3-3*[100-3*(100-\color{red}{3*33})]\} &= 2*\{100*3-3*[100-3*(\color{red}{100-99})]\} \\
&= 2*\{100*3-3*[100-\color{red}{3*(1)}]\} \\
&= 2*\{100*3-3*[\color{red}{100-3}]\} \\
&= 2*\{100*3-\color{red}{3*[97]}\} \\ 
&= 2*\{\color{red}{100*3}-291\} \\
&= 2*\{\color{red}{300-291}\} \\
&= \color{red}{2*\{9\}} \\
&= 18
\end{align}
$$
So for the first equality you find $3*33 = 99$. For the second equality you find $100 - 99 = 1$ and so on.